# MVC Binding a collection of things to different dropdowns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have a database table called `ItemAttributeLinks` and a collection of these too

```
Collection<ItemAttributeLink> ItemAttributeLinks
```

Now, in my view I do this in order to bind n dropdowns to the n items in this collection.  This does not work.  The values in `m.Item.ItemAttributeLinks` are always null.  The values in the dropdowns appear and are all correct, the issue is that the selected values, don't bind on postback.

```
@{
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var type in @Model.AttributeTypes)
            {
                <section>
                    <label>@type.Text</label>
                    <div> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item.ItemAttributeLinks[i] ,Model.AttributeValuesList[Convert.ToInt32(type.Value)], "Select a value")</div>
                </section>
                i++;
            }
```

The ItemAttributeLink table, incidentally, contains an int id, an int foreign key attributevalueid and an int foreign key ItemId.

What is the correct way to bind multiple dropdowns in this way?
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the dropdown to primitive types (such as integer, string, Guid, ...):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Item.ItemAttributeLinks[i].SomePrimitiveTypeProperty,
    Model.AttributeValuesList[Convert.ToInt32(type.Value)], 
    "Select a value"
)
```

and then inside your POST controller action the primitive types will be filled with the selected values. If you want to get the corresponding model you will have to query your database using the id.

Remember that in HTML, the `<select>` element (which is what the DropDownList helper generates) sends only the selected value when the form is submitted. You cannot bind it to complex types.